# Unable to zoom-in Munin graphs on CentOS

Tags: apache, apache2, centos6, munin

I have installed munin on my CentOS 6 system.
The installation procedure is as follows:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum --enablerepo=epel install munin munin-node rrdtool

vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf

htpasswd -cm /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd muninadmin

/etc/init.d/munin-node start

chkconfig munin-node on

service httpd restart
```

Url to check graphs - http://[MY_IP]/munin

In Munin.conf, replace the existing data with the following:

```
Alias /munin /var/www/html/munin

<Directory /var/www/html/munin>

  Options FollowSymLinks

  AllowOverride None

  Order allow,deny

  Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Am able to view all the graphs, but not able to zoom-in any of them.
I have attached the screenshot of the screen that I get when I try zooming.

[image]

Do we have any solutions for this? Am I missing something in the installation steps?

Comment: It seems that you missed the Apache configuration: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI#Apache2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where exactly are we to add this apache configuration? Any other configuration to be done along with this?

Comment: You have to save the configuration in your vHost settings. Generally, they are located in `/etc/httpd/sites-available/`.

Comment: I tried following the apache confiuration from the above link. But it didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this without any further tweaking from defaults in RHEL/CentOS7:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp

sudo chown apache:apache /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp
```

If you still get grief, use audit2allow to make sure you aren't getting dunked on by selinux.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the following:

```
chown -R munin:apache /var/log/munin/
systemctl restart httpd
```

and my /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf looks like this:

```
alias /munin /var/www/html/munin
ScriptAlias   /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /var/www/html/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph

#ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/ /var/www/html/munin/cgi/

# FastCGI
<Directory "/var/www/html/munin/cgi">
    Options +ExecCGI
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<directory /var/www/html/munin>
    Satisfy Any
</directory>
```